# How to queue music in a discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have created a discord.js bot that plays music using ytdl-core and it works well. However, when the same command is entered during the first song playing, the bot will stop playing music and leave. From extensive research conducted prior to this question being asked, I have discovered that I made my bot in a slightly different way which makes it difficult to find help. So my question is how do I add subsequent requests to a queue to be played.

Below is the file for the command play.

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const yt = require('ytdl-core');
const Bot = new Commando.Client();

class play extends Commando.Command {

    constructor(client){
        super(client, {
            name:'play',
            group:'play',
            memberName:'play',
            description:'plays videos from youtube'
        });
    }

    async run(message, args){

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel){
            return message.channel.sendMessage("you must be in a voice channel to request me");
        }

        if (args === ""){
            message.reply('i need a link to play a youtube video');
            console.log('message didnt send');
        }
        else {
            if (message.content.includes("http://") || message.content.includes("https://")) {
                if (message.content.includes("youtube") || message.content.includes("youtu.be")) {

                    message.channel.sendMessage(":white_check_mark: **connected**");
                    voiceChannel.join()
                    .then(connection => {
                        const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
                        let stream = yt(args.join(" "));
                        yt.getInfo(args.join(" "), function(err, info) {
                            const title = info.title
                            message.channel.sendMessage(`this song was requested \`${title}\`.)
                        })
                        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, {audioonly: true});
                        dispatcher.on('end', () => {

                            voiceChannel.leave();
                            message.channel.sendMessage('song finished')
                        }).catch(e =>{
                            console.error(e);
                        });
                    })
                } else {
                    message.reply('only youtube links are allowed');
                }
            } else {
                message.reply('only youtube links are allowed');
            }
        }
    }
}
module.exports = play;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-musicbot-addon) if you want an easy music function, it works quite well. although if you still want to make your own [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4S2qqX7YvA&) is a Youtube video that helped me with making a queue.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you have a similar setup as mine? (i.e commands in different folders/files)

Comment: I prefer to do all my code in the one file, to me it feels more organised, although my bot is very basic. I've opted to use the npm music bot add on for mine and use a set of basic commands and other things, such as a server level and a welcome message. I hope my answer helped you in some way :)